# Understanding round half even?

Tags: java, groovy, rounding

When i print

```
(new BigDecimal(5) * new BigDecimal(0.049))​
```

It gives

```
0.24500000000000000943689570931383059360086917877197265625
```

When i round it using the ROUND_HALF_EVEN

```
(new BigDecimal(5) * new BigDecimal(0.049)).setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN)​
```

It prints

```
0.25
```

So my confusion is, shouldn't it round to even number, so instead of 0.25 shouldn't it be 0.24. Please help with this confusion. Thanks!

Comment: Did you actually mean to start with exactly 0.049? If so, use `new BigDecimal("0.049")`. That way, the result is exactly 0.245. At *that* point you'll see `ROUND_HALF_EVEN` rounding to 0.24, because it's half way between 0.24 and 0.25.

Comment: ok this fixed it. looks like i need the quotes. plz put the answer. ill accept it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The REAL issue here is that you used the wrong constructor for the `BigDecimal`.

```
(new BigDecimal(5).multiply(new BigDecimal("0.049"))).setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN)​
```

will do what you want.

The problem is that `0.049` is a floating point literal, and that value is not representable exactly as a floating point value (neither `float` nor `double`), introducing a miniscule error that in this case is meaningful.

By using the constructor that accepts a `String` argument you avoid the conversion through floating point and get the exact value you intended.

Floating point arithmetic on computers is fraught with nasty unexpected behaviors due to its limited precision.  If you want to learn more about the pitfalls, read  [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BigDecimal result1 = (new BigDecimal(5).multiply(new BigDecimal("0.049"))).setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN);
    BigDecimal result2 = (new BigDecimal(5).multiply(new BigDecimal(0.049))).setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN);
    System.out.println(result1);
    System.out.println(result2);
}
```

Prints

```
0.24
0.25
```

Comment: Nit: 0.049 is a `double`, unless Groovy has different rules about floating point literals.

Answer (score 6):

> int java.math.BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN : 6 [0x6]
>
> Rounding mode to round towards the "nearest neighbor" unless both neighbors are equidistant, in which case, round towards the even neighbor.

`0.24500000000000000943689570931383059360086917877197265625` is closer to `0.25` than to `0.24`. The even neighbour is only chosen is the distance from both neighbors is equal (i.e. if you were trying to round `0.245`).

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal("0.245").setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN);
System.out.println (bd);
```

will print `0.24`.

Comment: I think this is a better answer than the accepted answer to the question because OP already knew precision was lost when he used `BigDecimal` constructor with non-string arguments. This answer also points out the behavior of `BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN` which is why OP did not get the expected value.